# Is there any Eigen value decomposition, which can be warm-started?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a Matrix, $A$ which is positive semidefinite. No consider, $B=A+\Delta$. I have Eigen decomposition of $A$ and $\Delta_{ij}<= \epsilon_1$, $\Vert \Delta \Vert_F <= \epsilon_2$.

Is there any method which can compute Eigen decomposition of $B$, starting from Eigen decomposition of $A$?

I assume that this will speed up the Eigen decomposition. Am I right? 
Isn't it an implementation of this in LAPACK/BLAS?

Comment: Yes, perturbatively. In books about quantum mechanics you will find details. Your matrix $A$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian.

Comment: I am not familiar with quantum mechanics and currently, I don't have time. Do you know any linear algebra literature for it?

Comment: Quite exhaustive is Kato's "Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators", the first chapter on finite-dimensionak systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in principle you can apply the inverse subspace iteration to compute select eigenpairs of $B$ using eigenvalues of $A$ to initialize the search.

However, unless $A$ is such that you can solve linear systems $(A + \sigma I)x = b$ using $O(n)$, rather than the usual $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations, you will *not* be able to do better than finding the eigendecomposition of $B$ from scratch using a the dense methods implemented in (SCA)LAPACK.

Even if you can solve the linear system in $O(n)$ time, you will discover that it is extremely difficult to get *all* $n$ eigenvalues using the inverse subspace iteration algorithm.

There is no algorithm implemented in (SCA)LAPACK which can exploit the eigendecomposition of $A$ to find the eigendecomposition of $B$. You will have to code the invers subspace iteration with Rayleigh-Ritz acceleration yourself.

Your notation implies that the perturbation is small, but you have not indicated if it is symmetric. You may very well end up in the situation were the perturbed matrix can not be diagonalized. There is a cure for this situation, but that is topic for another question.

Comment: Could you explain a little about when we can solve the linear system in $O(n)$ time?.  I found this method, http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/142156/BLWS.pdf. I didn't read the paper currently, but don't you think it has done what I'm looking for?

Comment: Many linear systems are sparse and can be solved using $O(n)$ arithmetic operations. We either use sparse direct solvers such as PARDISO, PSpike, Harwell Subroutine Library (HSL) or any number of preconditioned Krylov subspace methods. However, since you want the entire eigendecomposition of $B$ you are better off starting from scratch using a direct method. Browsing the paper I see nothing new nor anything which affects my original recommendation. It is a standard extension of the Lanczos method for finding the dominant eigenvalues of a matrix and not what you are looking for.